# Different images for different menus in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my WordPress menu I want different images for different menus with text as well. Here is the image reference. I want my menu should be like this.I am using WordPress 3.4.2. Any help and suggestions are highly appreciable.

[image]

**Update**
The screen options image[image]

Comment: yes..A child theme of twentyeleven..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways on how you could add custom classes to your menu items, so that you could style them with CSS.

1. When on the `Appearance > Menus` page in Wordpress admin panel, click on `Screen
   Options` at the top-right of the page. A slide-out menu appears and
   allows you to check an option labeled `CSS Classes`. If you enable
   this option, you will be able to add a custom class to each menu
   item, the same way as you add its title.
2. You can customize the `Walker` class to add an incremental class name
   to each (top-level) element. To see how the Walker class works,
   please take a look at the following article:
   http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/

Comment: @Lazer Vuckovic thanks for your reply.
I tried your first option and that is the `screen option` but there is no option called as CSS Classes found. I have uploaded the picture in question. You can check that there.

Comment: @NewUser - the screen options are different on every page depending on which section you are in.  That screenshot in your edit is not from the menu options, go to Appearance->Menus and the Screen Options there will allow you to activate Classes per list item.

Comment: @McNab Thanks for adding the Appearance part, which I forgot to mention. I'll edit the answer to add it in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use image sprites
2. Use a different class for each of your `<li>` item
3. Position your images as background for that classes.

Comment: Yes I know that but how to add different classes to each `li` as wordpress generates its class.

Comment: You could use the `:nth-child(n)` selector. Like `li:first-child {} li:nth-child(2){} li:nth-child(3){}` and so on

Comment: Inspect the classes generated by Wordpress. Each li may have its own class, which you can use to manipulate the css.